# GCM Can same Server key be used with different sender IDs

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have generated a GCM Server API Key (from API Console) and store it in my backend server. Now I have to create several Playstore developer accounts to upload separate apps for each of my client. 
Can I use Same server Key which I generated earlier with each of the Sender ID (different for each account) or a server key and Sender ID has 1 to 1 relationship?

Comment: I think without sender id you can not get device id so my answer is no. you can not use same server key with several sender ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use same server key with different sender ID, they work as a combination. And yes they have a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.